# Printing multiple alphabets or a name in '*' format in python

Tags: python

I have been givena task to print my name 'KA' in '*' format using python

output

[image]

code:

```
#k
i=0
j=4
for row in range(7):
    for col in range(5):
        if col==0 or (row==col+2 and col>1):
            print("*",end="")
        elif((row==i and col==j)and col>0):
            print('*',end="")
            i=i+1
            j=j-1
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()

#aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

for row in range(7):
    for col in range(5):
        if ((col==0 or col==4)and row!=0)or ((row==0 or row==3)and (col>0 and col<4)):
            print("*",end="")

        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

I can able to write code for individual alphabets but they are expecting to use only two for loops and the output to be printed side by side(KA...in this format). Tried to merge the programs but I am getting the merged output. Any guidance?

Comment: You need bitmaps for individual characters; usually hard-coded.

Comment: I don't have much idea about it. Could you just post some sample code so that I can try.

Comment: You'd find many of them online. e.g. http://patorjk.com/software/taag-v1/ - Use Font=Contrast in that link.

Comment: Font = Star Strips is much better I think.

Comment: Why should we do your homework for you? As @anishsane hinted you should store the characters as bitmaps. Then iterate over the rows of each character bitmap in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 

It is a different approach. Its nothing but adding each letter into a list first. 
You see each list contains layers of a letter and these lists are added to a dictionary.
so when you want to print K A, the first layer of K and A will be printed (Here K and A are the keys in the dictionary,stars at first index of K and A to be precise),then goes to second (stars at second index of K and A) and continues.

```
options = {
       'A':['  *  ',' * * ','*****','*   *','*   *'],
       'B':['**** ','*   *','*****','*   *','**** '],
       'C':[' ****','*    ','*    ','*    ',' ****'],
       'K':['*   *','*  * ','***  ','*  * ','*   *'],
       }  # add more letters

def print_big(newList):
   for i in range(5):  # length of a list in dictionary is 5
       for j,_ in enumerate(newList):
           print(options[newList[j]][i]+"   ",end = " ")
       print()

name = "AK"
print_big(list(name))
```

**Output**:

```
*   *      *      
*  *      * *     
***      *****    
*  *     *   *    
*   *    *   *
```

name = "ABC"

```
  *      ****      ****    
 * *     *   *    *        
*****    *****    *        
*   *    *   *    *        
*   *    ****      ****
```

Comment: Not only is this just a code dump, which doesn't make for a good SO answer, the code isn't great. You compare a list to a string in two different places, the style isn't PEP8 compliant, you loop over a range where you shouldn't, ...

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you. Can you explain me in detail?

Comment: `userIn = [...]` will return you a list. You are comparing it with `"exit"` and `""`, which are srings.

Comment: Oops I got it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Mufeed how can we customize it? I mean can we pass the values without hardcoding them? For example, if I want to print RAJ by inputting it dynamically. how can i do that using this code?

Comment: You mean you want to add any name and print accordingly?

Comment: You can. Only requirement is that you need to have each letter in the dictionary(which is obvious).

Comment: By "dynamically" you mean getting input from console?

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = {
    'A': [' *** ', '*   *', '*****', '*   *', '*   *'],
    'B': ['**** ', '*   *', '**** ', '*   *', '**** '],
    'C': [' ****', '*    ', '*    ', '*    ', ' ****'],
    'D': ['**** ', '*   *', '*   *', '*   *', '**** '],
    'E': ['*****', '*    ', '*****', '*    ', '*****'],
    'F': ['*****', '*    ', '***  ', '*    ', '*    '],
    'G': [' ****', '*    ', '*  **', '*   *', ' ****'],
    'H': ['*   *', '*   *', '*****', '*   *', '*   *'],
    'I': ['*****', '  *  ', '  *  ', '  *  ', '*****'],
    'J': ['*****', '    *', '    *', '*   *', ' *** '],
    'K': ['*   *', '*  * ', '**   ', '*  * ', '*   *'],
    'L': ['*    ', '*    ', '*    ', '*    ', '*****'],
    'M': ['*   *', '** **', '* * *', '*   *', '*   *'],
    'N': ['*   *', '**  *', '* * *', '*  **', '*   *'],
    'O': [' *** ', '*   *', '*   *', '*   *', ' *** '],
    'P': ['**** ', '*   *', '**** ', '*    ', '*    '],
    'Q': [' *** ', '*   *', '*   *', '*  **', ' ** *'],
    'R': ['**** ', '*   *', '**** ', '*  * ', '*   *'],
    'S': [' ****', '*    ', '**** ', '    *', '**** '],
    'T': ['*****', '  *  ', '  *  ', '  *  ', '  *  '],
    'U': ['*   *', '*   *', '*   *', '*   *', ' *** '],
    'V': ['*   *', '*   *', '*   *', ' * * ', '  *  '],
    'W': ['*   *', '*   *', '* * *', '** **', '*   *'],
    'X': ['*   *', ' * * ', '  *  ', ' * * ', '*   *'],
    'Y': ['*   *', ' * * ', '  *  ', '  *  ', '  *  '],
    'Z': ['*****', '   * ', '  *  ', ' *   ', '*****'],
}

string = "Sandesh"

#print(len(string))
for i in range(5):

    for word in range(len(string)):
        current_word = string[word].upper()
        #print(current_word)
        if word == len(string)-1 :
            print(letters[current_word][i])
        else :
            print(letters[current_word][i],end='  ')

#TRY THIS, I HAVE CREATED A DICTIONARY(MADE BY ME).
```